# Is there a random letter generator with a range?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a random letter generator in Python that takes a range as parameter?
For example, if I wanted a range between A and D? I know you can use this as a generator:

```
import random
import string

random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

But it doesn't allow you to supply it a range.

Comment: `random.choice('ABCD')` ???

Comment: You could get a random number between 65 and 90 and then convert that to the ASCII character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can slice `string.ascii_letters`:

```
random.choice(string.ascii_letters[0:4])
```

Answer (score 5):

Ascii is represented with numbers, so you can random a number in the range that you prefer and then cast it to char.

Answer (score 4):

String slicing would be my solution to this

```
random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:4])
```

This would randomly choose one of the first 4 letters of the alphabet. Obviously 4 could be any value.

Answer (score 3):

The function `choice` takes a general sequence.

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

In particular

```
random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

will do what you want.

You can easily generate the range programatically:

```
random.choice([chr(c) for c in xrange(ord('A'), ord('D')+1)])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> random.choice('ABCD')
'C'
```

Or if it's a larger range so you don't want to type them all out:

```
>>> chr(random.randint(ord('I'), ord('Q')))
'O'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially define such a thing:

```
def letters_in_range(start_letter, end_letter):
   start_index = string.ascii_letters.find(start_letter)
   end_index = string.ascii_letters.find(end_letter)
   assert start_index != -1
   assert end_index != -1
   assert start_letter < end_letter
   return string.ascii_letters[start_index:end_index]
```

With the above:

```
 random.choice(letters_in_range('A', 'D'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your original way of getting a random letter you can simply make a function as such.

```
def getLetter(start, stop):
    letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    while letter < start and letter > stop:
        letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    return letter
```

Calling it like `getLetter('a', 'd')`

Answer (score 1):

Saw this and thought the algorithm I just wrote might be helpful.  This generates a random uppercase ascii string of N length:

```
from random import randint

def generate_random_nlength_string(n):
    prandstr = [chr(randint(65,90)) for _ in range(n)]
    return ''.join(prandstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own letter range iterator and choose from it randomly:

```
import random


def letter_range(start, stop, step=1):
    """Yield a range of lowercase letters.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> list(letter_range("a", "f"))
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

    >>> list(letter_range("a", "f", step=2))
    ['a', 'c', 'e']

    """
    start = ord(start.lower())
    stop = ord(stop.lower())
    for ord_ in range(start, stop, step):
        yield chr(ord_)


letters = list(letter_range("a", "g"))
random.choice(letters)
# "e"
```